# Did Cimabue also paint the Last Supper?

Tags: middle-ages, art

May I ask if the painter Cimabue also painted the Last Supper? I am trying to draw some comparison between the different paintings of The Last Supper in different eras... But Cimabue (1240-1302) has many famous paintings, but I cannot find any evidence of his artwork of the last supper besides the tag in Wikipedia. Please confirm this thanks

[image: painting of the Last Supper]

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know if Cimabue painted the Last Supper or not, but this particular artwork is held by the New Orleans Museum of Art [which states the artists is "unidentified"](https://noma.org/collection/the-last-supper/). Not sure how it ended up attributed to Cimabue on Wikipedia - they claim to have sourced from the Kress Foundation (who donated it to NOMA), but Kress' website likewise lists the artist as "Anonymous".